# how to get jpl latest version: jpl7?

Tags: java, swi-prolog, jpl

I'm using a java project with the jpl library, but i'm getting the compile error "the package org.jpl7 does not exist". I've tried to download the latest version, but I've probably get the jpl3 version.

How to get the latest version of jpl7? I've searched extensively, and even found the http://jpl7.org, but there is no hint about how to download that version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will find it on Maven, look for it on Maven Central!